# Negative Math.log return might harm Kt/V calculation

Tags: java

I am new at java programming and using it's Math classes, so probably my question is an rookie's one and solution is obvious. Yet I'd rather risk my reputation here and be downvoted to hell's pit if that's what it takes for someone to tell me where am I mistaken.
So here's simple code that supposed to calculate singlepool KT/V (calculation made in nephrology) by the formula `spKT/V = -ln(R - 0.008 * t) + (4 - 3.5 * R) * 0.55 * (UF/V)`
I have a text book where KT/V with mentioned values:
R = 0.35, t = 3, UF/V = 0.06 is somehow endup with result 1.21.
Me running this class after compilation getting -1.029.
I have 2 questions:
1. why am I getting negative number and how to change it to positive? (guess, it have something to do with Math log)
2. Is it something I messed up with the code or textbook is wrong? If that is me who wrong what to change to get 1.21?

Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks to everyone in advance.

```
import java.*;
public class nephro {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println(spKTV());

}
public static double logrfm() {
    double logX = x(0.35, 3);
    double left = Math.log(logX);
    return left;
}
public static double x(double R, double t) {
    double x_res = (R - 0.008 * t);
    return x_res;
}
public static double rufv (double R, double UFV) {
    double rufv = (4 - 3.5 * R) * (0.55 * UFV);
    return rufv;
}
public static double spKTV(){
    double result = logrfm() + rufv(0.35, 0.06);
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: You forget to negate the result of the log

Comment: @harold what do you mean log? Code compiles and works perfectly, I just dissatisfied with result.

Comment: That `-ln` in the formula. In the code you take a log and then you *don't* negate it.

Comment: @harold yep, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you explicitly declare all whole numbers you use as double values, i.e. `3d` and `4d` for sanity's sake.

Comment: @Compass yeah, didn't notice that. Sanity is overrated though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You got a negative value because there is a mistake in the calculation.

2) The book is right (you can check this with a pocket calculator). The problem in the code is here:

```
double left = Math.log(logX);
```

which should be instead:

```
double left = - Math.log(logX);
```

Btw. the code would be somewhat easier to understand if it were not split up into so many methods.

Comment: thank you! Works now. «Everything comes with experience» as they say.